# What are good options for affordable consultations on U.S. law that can be reached from overseas?

Tags: united-states, lawyer, civil-legal-system

I have a U.S. legal problem and would like to know if there are places I could either call or email to get some legal advice relatively cheaply?  Unfortunately I am outside of the U.S., so visiting an office in the U.S. is not an option.

This is regarding civil law in an educational setting.

Where I live, there are lawyers appointed by public offices that give free legal advice over the phone/email/visitation.  Is there anything like that in the U.S.?

Comment: Where do you live?  I am not aware of anything like that for civil matters in the U.S.  However, it did just occur to me that a lot of U.S. law firms outsource paralegal work to offshore companies (LPOs).  I wonder if any of those would provide remote U.S. legal services to individuals, given that they are likely exempt from U.S. rules against the Unlicensed Practice of Law.

Comment: Depending on the type of law you are looking for, you should lookup pro bono services. Many large firms require a certain number of pro bono hours. Additionally, many legal clinics offer pro bono services.

Comment: I have no experience or knowledge of the following other than what appears on their homepages, but if you have no idea where to start you might check out legalzoom.com or legal.io

Comment: You didn't say which State this is about? Each State has its own Bar association, and many of those Bar Associations can provide free 30 minutes telephone consultations.

Answer (score 1):

You might try reaching out to the [Education Law Center.](http://www.edlawcenter.org/) They may be able to provide information, or a referral to another organization or law office. Intake information is on the [contact page](http://www.edlawcenter.org/about/contact-us.html).